# Restore values of Response JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest-assured

I'm having some problems to get the values and storage in a list to check if these values exist inside the other list.

Somebody can help?

This is my code: (get response using RestAssured)

```
public static ArrayList<String> JSONcounterparties(String date ) { 
        baseURI = uri;

        ArrayList<String> accounts = 
                    given() 
                        .auth().basic(getJiraUser(), getJiraPass())
                        .param("date", date)
                        .param("limit", "1")
                        .param("count", "false")
                        .param("sort", "accountId")
                    .when()
                        .get("/counterparties.json")
                    .then() 
                        .extract().path("accounts.account.identifiers.identifier.accountId"); 
        
        return accounts;
    }
```

So far so good, I get the expected values.
There are the values that I need to extract. For every 3 arrays like this, I need to get the values and put them in a list to do a check with another list. If the values exist within the list then "ok" else "not ok".

```
 [[[MHI, AIGSALPPMM, AIGSALPPM, 0, AIGSALPPMM, MORLGB2LXXX, AIGSALPPMM]]]
```

I tried to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        ArrayList<String> dataJSON = JSONcounterparties("2021-05-25");
        ArrayList<String> getData = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < dataJSON.size(); i++) {
            String data = dataJSON.get(i);
            getData.add(data);
            
            System.out.println(getData);
        }
```

But, I'm receiving this exception in my console:
  `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

To do the check after I get the values:

```
public static void compareAndCheck(List<String> inputs, List<String> outputs) {
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;

        try {
            for (String input : inputs) {
                for (String out : outputs) {
                    if (input.contains(out)) {
                        System.out.println("ok: " + input + " exist in CDW");
                        
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("not Ok: " + input + " don't exist in CDW");
                    }
                }
                x = x + 1;
            }
            y = y + 1; 
            x = 0; 
            
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

JSON

```
"accounts": {
    "account": [{
        "organisationId": {
            "#value": "MHI"
        },
        "accountName": "AVIVA INVESTORS AC ALP PM MAIN",
        "identifiers": {
            "accountId": "AIGSALPPMM",
            "customerId": "AIGSALPPM",
            "cedol": "0",
            "blockAccountCode": "AIGSALPPMM",
            "bic": "MORLGB2LXXX",
            "identifier": [{
                    "accountId": "MHI",
                    "accountIdType": "REVNCNTR"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "AIGSALPPMM",
                    "accountIdType": "ACCOUNTID"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "AIGSALPPM",
                    "accountIdType": "MHICUSTID"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "0",
                    "accountIdType": "CEDOL"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "AIGSALPPMM",
                    "accountIdType": "BLOCKACCOUNT"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "MORLGB2LXXX",
                    "accountIdType": "ACCOUNTBIC"
                },
                {
                    "accountId": "AIGSALPPMM",
                    "accountIdType": "GLOBEOP"
                }
            ]
        },
        "isBlocAccount": "N",
        "accountStatus": "COMPLETE",
        "products": {
            "productType": [{
                "productLineName": "REPO",
                "productTypeId": "PRODMHI4",
                "productTypeName": "Fixed Income",
                "limitQualifier": "GMRA 2000",
                "repoWrittenAgreement": "Y",
                "repoNetting": "Y",
                "repoAgreementDate": "2012-04-04",
                "cleared": "N",
                "bilateral": "N",
                "limitInstructions": {
                    "limitInstruction": [{
                            "limitAmount": "0",
                            "limitCurrency": "USD",
                            "limitType": "REPEEXLI",
                            "limitTypeName": "Repo-FI Peak Exposure limit"
                        },
                        {
                            "limitAmount": "0",
                            "limitCurrency": "USD",
                            "limitType": "RENCBOLI",
                            "limitTypeName": "Repo-FI Non Correlated Borrow Limit"
                        },
                        {
                            "limitAmount": "0",
                            "limitCurrency": "GBP",
                            "limitType": "REDOTHLI",
                            "limitTypeName": "Repo-FI Documentated Threshold Limit"
                        },
                        {
                            "limitAmount": "0",
                            "limitCurrency": "USD",
                            "limitType": "REPTENLI",
                            "limitTypeName": "Repo-FI Tenor Limit"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }]
        },
        "clientBroker": "C",
        "traxFlag": "N",
        "clientLevel": "SUBAC",
        "accountCreationDate": "2014-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "accountOpeningDate": "2013-07-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Because this code is `List<List<List<String>>>`, not a `List<String>`

```
[[[MHI, AIGSALPPMM, AIGSALPPM, 0, AIGSALPPMM, MORLGB2LXXX, AIGSALPPMM]]]
```

When you try to get element from this List

```
String data = dataJSON.get(i);
```

This will throw Exception ClassCastException, ArrayList cannot be cast to String.

**Solution**

Save response to `List<List<List<String>>>`

```
List<List<List<String>>> accounts = ...extract().path("accounts.account.identifiers.identifier.accountId");
```

Convert  `List<List<List<String>>>` to `List<String>`

```
List<String> accountIds = accounts.stream()
                .flatMap(l -> l.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucasnguyen17, but I am still getting the same response:  [[[MHI, AIGSALPPMM, AIGSALPPM, 0, AIGSALPPMM, MORLGB2LXXX, AIGSALPPMM]]]

Comment: could you provide the response?

Comment: Yes, I added the response as a image. You can find it above

Comment: Pls provide raw json response, I cannot do anything with your image.

Comment: Ok, I put here a part of JSON. I need "acountId" , following this path "accounts.account.identifiers.identifier.accountId".

Comment: I updated the solution by adding one extra step to covert `List<List<List<String>>>` to `List<String>`

Comment: Thank you very much @lucasnguyen17, this solved my problem.